# Cannot connect to MySQL. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sockets

I'm on a Chromebook using Crouton Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS.

Error message: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I've looked at other posts with the same problem and none of the solutions have worked for me. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I tried changing the socket in the my.cfg file. Please help.

Comment: 1) Have you verified that you have a mysqld process running at all? 2) If it is indeed running: check what ports/sockets it is listening on with sudo netstat -lnp | grep mysqld

Comment: It is not running.

Comment: Restart MySQL:  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` - Tell me what you get.

Comment: If all else fails, uninstall & reinstall. Unistall: `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`, then do a fresh install of MySQL.

Comment: You cld also try: `chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*` and `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ] 
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [fail]

Comment: Also I tried reinstalling and uninstalling. I can't find the mysqld.sock file. It doesn't exist. So I guess it's trying to find a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I stopped using MySQL a few years ago and switched over to MariaDB. I run that on my production server...and it doesn't use mysqld.sock. https://downloads.mariadb.org

Comment: OK ill try that. Appreciate your help.